# Laravel 5.4 - filter authenticated users

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to filter my navbar upon a column in my users table which is user_type.
user type column has student, Coordinator and admin.
I am able to restrict the buttons of my navbar to only authenticated users using

```
@if(!Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="/myprojects">My projects</a></li>
@endif
```

but I am trying to show some buttons only from the Coordinator, how I am able to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin')
        <li><a href="/admin">Admin Panel</a></li>
        // your logic
    @elseif(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Coordinator')
        // your logic
    @else
        // your logic   
    @endif
@else
    // your logic
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, been struggling for hours